# Spliting of image on the basis of color of line

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I want to split an image on the basis of color of the line.

I'm using hough line detector to detect a line and mark it with red color.

Now,i want to split the image on the basis of line which has been overlayed using line detection algorithm.

[Image with line detection overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRbWW.png)

i want to split the above image into two.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @xdurch0 check the image there's image with red line on it . i want to split the image on the reference of that red overlay line into two parts.

Comment: That is not a question. This website is not a free do-your-work-for-you service. You should put some effort into finding a solution yourself and come back when/if you have a concrete programming-related question. Also see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the line always roughly horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Imagemagick with some Unix shell commands as follows. The basic idea is to average the image to one column, then search the column for the y coordinate of the red pixel. Then use that to crop the image into two parts.

INPUT:

[image]

```
width=$(convert -ping tRbWW.png -format "%w" info:)
height=$(convert -ping tRbWW.png -format "%h" info:)
y=$(convert tRbWW.png -alpha off -scale 1x! -fuzz 20% -fill red -opaque red txt:- | grep "red" | head -n 1 | cut -d: -f1 | cut -d, -f2)
height1=$((y+1))
height2=$((height-y+1))
convert tRbWW.png \
\( -clone 0 -gravity north -crop ${width}x${height1}+0+0 +repage +write top.png \) \
\( -clone 0 -gravity south -crop ${width}x${height2}+0+0 +repage +write bottom.png \) \
null:
```

Top:

[image]

Bottom:

[image]